# How to get a string from lua file to c++

Tags: c++, string, lua, char

I am trying to get a string from lua into a char in c++. But for some reason it returns either a pointer or a number. I can use all the help I get on this one. Here is a example of what i'm trying to do:

Lua file:

```
logo = "ad.png"
```

C file:

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
luaL_dofile(L,"fuel.lua");
const char* logoX;

lua_getglobal(L, "logo");
if(lua_isnil(L,-1)){
    printf("is nil!\n");
}
else{
    logoX = lua_tostring(L, -1);
    printf("the logo is %d\n", *logoX);
}
```

But this is printing out text that says "the logo is 105". Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You use `%d` in your `printf`, shouldn't that be `%s`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `printf` statement:

```
printf("the logo is %d\n", *logoX);
```

You are using an integer format string (`%d`), and you are sending a character argument (`*logoX` which is the first character of your string). So the printed value is the string's first character integer value.

To make it work, change the `printf` statement to:

```
printf("the logo is %s\n", logoX);
```